# How to read only one line from a file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I tried to read the first line of a file, but when I tried to give to text, which was saved in the file, it prints out the whole file, not only one line. The tool is also **not** looking after breaks or spaces.

I'm using the following code:

```
//Vocabel.dat wird eingelesen
ifstream f;                         // Datei-Handle
string s;

f.open("Vocabeln.dat", ios::in);    // Öffne Datei aus Parameter
while (!f.eof())                    // Solange noch Daten vorliegen
{
    getline(f, s);                  // Lese eine Zeile
    cout << s;
}

f.close();                          // Datei wieder schließen
getchar();
```

Comment: I think that minimal programming knowledge is required on this site...

Comment: You want one line, but you're looping and getting a line each time? If you do that, though, 
`while (getline (f, s))`.

Comment: A helpful advice: C++ is in English, so the comments should also be in that language...

Comment: The comments even explain that this code will loop as long as there is more data (although it has a bug which processes the last line twice).  How did you end up with code comments in a language (German) you apparently don't understand?

Comment: @EitanT: wha?  Comments are to be read.  You write them in the language of the author(s) and maintainer(s).

Comment: @Joe I disagree, especially when this code is to be read by other people on the internet. But let's leave it aside, it's off-topic...

Comment: @EitanT: C++ is in English? That's _helpful advice_? It looks more like xenophobia to me. (By the way: in English, we never say "a helpful advice". Advice is not a countable noun, so you have to say "some helpful advice" or just "heplful advice".  HTH.)

Comment: @TonyK a. I appreciate your correcting my grammar, albeit 9 years late ;) b. This advice is for keeping the comments readable as much as possible (i.e written in a universally spoken language). What was the point of your ad hominem comment? But again, off-topic. Let's not get dragged into this pointless discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of your `while` loop. Replace this:

```
  while (!f.eof())                    // Solange noch Daten vorliegen
  {
    getline(f, s);                  // Lese eine Zeile
    cout << s;
  }
```

Wit this:

```
  if(getline(f, s))
    cout << s;
```

---

**EDIT**: Responding to the new requirement "that it read a line wich i can define in second variable ?"

For that, you'll need to loop, reading each line in turn, until you've read the line you care about:

```
// int the_line_I_care_about;  // holds the line number you are searching for
int current_line = 0;          // 0-based. First line is "0", second is "1", etc.
while( std::getline(f,s) )     // NEVER say 'f.eof()' as a loop condition
{
  if(current_line == the_line_I_care_about) {
    // We have reached our target line
    std::cout << s;            // Display the target line
    break;                     // Exit loop so we only print ONE line, not many
  }
  current_line++;              // We haven't found our line yet, so repeat.
}
```